# Recursively read a directories with a folder

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fs

I've been trying to request a recursively read a directory with **fs** module. I had problems along the way, its only giving me  a file name. Here's how I need it to be:

- File name.
- And also a directory of that file.
  This results may be as an object or bulked into an array.

Anyone please help.
Thanks.

Comment: _"And also a directory of that file"_ you already have this, otherwise the fs method used wouldn't know which directory you were trying to read. If you mean the path for each sub directory, well just concatenate each sub directory name to the path as you go deeper. But without seeing your code we can't tell you specifically how to fix your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution. You can test it, save it in a file, run `node yourfile.js /the/path/to/traverse`.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const util = require('util');

const traverse = function(dir, result = []) {
    
    // list files in directory and loop through
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach((file) => {
        
        // builds full path of file
        const fPath = path.resolve(dir, file);
        
        // prepare stats obj
        const fileStats = { file, path: fPath };

        // is the file a directory ? 
        // if yes, traverse it also, if no just add it to the result
        if (fs.statSync(fPath).isDirectory()) {
            fileStats.type = 'dir';
            fileStats.files = [];
            result.push(fileStats);
            return traverse(fPath, fileStats.files)
        }

        fileStats.type = 'file';
        result.push(fileStats);
    });
    return result;
};

console.log(util.inspect(traverse(process.argv[2]), false, null));
```

Output looks like this :

```
[
  {
    file: 'index.js',
    path: '/stackoverflow/test-class/index.js',
    type: 'file'
  },
  {
    file: 'message.js',
    path: '/stackoverflow/test-class/message.js',
    type: 'file'
  },
  {
    file: 'somefolder',
    path: '/stackoverflow/test-class/somefolder',
    type: 'dir',
    files: [{
      file: 'somefile.js',
      path: '/stackoverflow/test-class/somefolder/somefile.js',
      type: 'file'
    }]
  },
  {
    file: 'test',
    path: '/stackoverflow/test-class/test',
    type: 'file'
  },
  {
    file: 'test.c',
    path: '/stackoverflow/test-class/test.c',
    type: 'file'
  }
]
```